# how to set cursor position out off the application window? (c++)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mouse

I'm creating an application using C++ to set the cursor position even when the mouse is out off the application window...
 the `Win32` library has the `SetCursorPos` function which according to the documentation

> A window should move the cursor only when the cursor is in the window's client area

however I want to move the cursor outside the window : EVEN when the window IS HIDDEN...
I want it to be more like a mouse driver : windows reads the cursor position from it...

Comment: This is a duplicate of quite a few posts. Just do a google search for "set cursor position c++ winapi"

Comment: Notice it says "should", as in you probably shouldn't do otherwise, but it's up to you.

Comment: @pepperjack it isn't a duplicate I read all of the others and none of them helped...

Comment: @tadman I just want my application to be able to CONTROL the cursor position when the application window is hidden...

Comment: So did you try using that function?

Comment: `SetCursorPos()` works just fine to move the cursor anywhere onscreen whether the app window is hidden or not. The cursor is not tied to any particular window.

Comment: @RemyLebeau THaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank youuu I tried it and it worked just fine outside the window

Answer (score -1):

it seems that although the documentation says :

> A window should move the cursor only when the cursor is in the window's client area

it can control the mouse even when the window is HIDDEN